# Paypal Connection Timedout

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I was trying to setup paypal checkout via composer and when I run it, it gives me a connection timed out exception when running it in our live site, but it's working perfectly in my localhost. I'm using Laravel framework at the moment.
[Exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIvqe.png)

Here are the codes used for it

$payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

```
    $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
    $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
    // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
    // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

    $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

    $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PaypalController@getDone'));
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('PaypalController@getCancel'));

    $payment = PayPal::Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale');
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

    return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
```